# Redirect user to login page on timeout and when forced logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, redirect

I'm using custom membership provider and MVC4 in my project.

I have two scenarios to handle related to authentication:

1. Redirect user to login page when authentication has timed out.

   - For this I have tried using following code in both Logout action and Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax.cs file. Placing this code in Logout action didn't help and I wasn't sure about the performance hit by putting the following code in Application_BeginRequest()

     ```
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
     Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
     ```
2. For some cases, I want to forcefully logout user and after that redirect to login page.

   - If I redirect from Application_AuthorizeRequest in Global.asax.cs then the website goes in redirect loop.

Any suggestions or references please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will asume you're using cookie based authentication. For timeout logout you should use the default forms authentication cookie mechanism. Currently you're disabling cache on user logout, but you need to remove/invalidate the session or authentication cookie too.

First in your web.config you should have this element:

```
<authentication>
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

then in your Logout method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

// invalidate authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

You can mix this code with some fancy jQuery / Vanilla JavaScript routine to automatically logout users after inactivity period, improving user experience. Some people experimented odd behavior when invalidate cookies and redirect users to another url, this issue is related to how browsers parse 301 responses, to avoid this problem you could return the login view from logout method directly

Comment: Thank you Kellerman Rivero for your response. I tried your suggestion but  I can still go to the previous page after logout. The reason is mainly it's a cached page and hitting browser back button doesn't refresh the page so the `Request.IsAuthenticated` piece doesn't get executed.

Comment: You need to mix the code from the answer with the code you wrote previously when you invalidate cache. So in conclusion a good logout approach is to invalidate cache and authentication cookies.

Comment: This is what my logout action looks like. Still I can go back to the previous page which mean cache is still not clearing out.

Comment: `var user = CurrentUserHelper.Identity;              FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  Session.Abandon();  // invalidate authentication cookie  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");              cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);              Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));  Response.Cache.SetNoStore();  _logger.Debug(string.Format("User {0} logged out.", user.UserEmail));  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");`